# Error:Xamarin.Forms targets have been imported multiple times

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

a few hours ago, my solution just builds success, but after that it has error "Xamarin.Forms targets have been imported multiple times." I have struggled with that a whole week.
[image]

my project here:

[file my project](https://1drv.ms/w/s!Aq0EBpHP3dwxpJRaW2Mz251N2lwuJA)

I didn't see any multiple xamarin.forms at all.

Comment: Please add the errors and code always as text and not images as that makes it tougher to understand if anything is clipped

Comment: thank you G.hakim, I'll do it next one

Comment: @Lucas Zhang - MSFT. Yes that worked for me. They where called `XamarinApp.csproj.nuget.g.props` and `XamarinApp.csproj.nuget.g.targets` in Visual studio for mac and residing inside `obj` folder of the projects. You can give that as an answer?

Answer (score 13):

This can be because of the move to using PackageReference for your NuGet packages and a simple fix awaits you.

1.Close Visual Studio and navigate to the Solution in File Explorer Delete the hidden .vs folder .

2.Go into each affected project sub folder and delete the following files; project_name.nuget.props and project_name.nuget.targets .

3.Open the solution in Visual Studio, do a Clean and Rebuild.

Answer (score 3):

We have encountered the same issue several times. the solution is simple

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Clean the solution manually. Delete the `bin` and `obj` folders of the project
3. Reopen Visual Studio and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

This solution might help, we encountered same issue in recent past.

Remove and add packages back will help you.

Steps:
Keep back up of your packages.config file.
Remove all packages from packages.config file.
Close project and open app again.
Copy backup file content, Clear project and build again. It will clear issue.

Comment: Hi Ramu, I did all step like above, so it has a new error:  Your project does not reference "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1" framework. Add a reference to "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1" in the "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet restore.
Can you resolve that ?, please

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project and select Edit Project File

In the section that has all your imports, ie

You will probably find that there are two imports of Xamarin.Forms, ie ...packages\Xamarin.Forms...

You can delete one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all solutions and they did not work

The solution that worked right:

1-Right Click on ProjectName inside solution

2-Unload Project

3-Edit $ProjectName$.csproj

4-Remove All

```
 <Import Project="" />
 <Reference Include="FormsViewGroup">
    <HintPath>
$(SolutionDir)\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.0.0.482510\lib\MonoAndroid10\FormsViewGroup.dll
    </HintPath>
  </Reference>
```

5-Reload Project

6-Add NugetPackage

7-Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above but not working, then I found that the warning actually says it clearly, I have 2 lines of the same code in the .csproject (but in different lines)

```
<Import Project="..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.4.7.0.1179\build\Xamarin.Forms.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.4.7.0.1179\build\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" />
```

Then I remove 1 of them, then the error goes away.