# Xamarin.Forms targets have been imported multiple times

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Working with VS-2017.

I get this following error:

> Xamarin.Forms targets have been imported multiple times. Please check your project file and remove the duplicate ones.

checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54683961/errorxamarin-forms-targets-have-been-imported-multiple-times) but could not find project_name.nuget.props and project_name.nuget.targets in my project.

Any help how to proceed with this?

Comment: it could be a totally different base name, check all your ***.targets|props files and see if you have dups...

Comment: Can you post csproj content to investigate? If not just create new project through vs 2019 and modify old csproj comparing with that.

Comment: @Prateek yes I found duplicate import statements for xamarin.forms. Removed them and the errors are gone. But then I end up getting new error - "XamlCtask could not be instantiated". Again when I update the xamarin forms, this error goes away,and the original error is back